# вот мой код ,при добавлении я написал в нём тег видео ,а при выполнении кода самого видео нет а только панель управления как для аудио файла

Tags: html5

```
<video
  controls
  src="1 сезон видео/Ходячие мертвецы (1 серия) BDRip1080p от NOLIMITS-TEAM.mp4"></video>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Правильный формат:

```
<video>
 <source src="URL">
</video>
```

где путь до видео указывается в специальном теге `source` с атрибутом, а не прямо в `video`

---

http://htmlbook.ru/html/video